# Записать данные в application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties

```
@Service
@PropertySource(value = "application.properties")
public class SomeClass {

    private String someField;
```

Есть класс с неким полем и в какой-то момент коде этому полю присваивается значение. Как записать это значение в application.properties?
Есть ли в Spring Boot для этого аннотация на подобии @Value("${class.field}")

Comment: Аннотация `@Value` подтягивает значение из `.properties` в поле объекта, причём не в "какой-то момент", а при создании объекта. А аннотация, делающая обратное действие, вряд ли существует, хотя точно не уверен. Если вы это значение устанавливаете как-то геттерами, то можно, например, через АОП добавить геттеру запись устанавливаемого значения в файл. Очень специфическая задача, особенно учитывая, что вы хотите значение записать аж в `.properties`.

Comment: Нельзя, "закон обратной силы не имеет". Даже теоретически - это невозможно. В properties (или yaml) значения может не быть: оно может находиться в таком же файле конкретного профиля (перекрывая или дополняя значения в основном файле), может задаваться через параметры командной строки или переменные окружения.

Comment: @kami, вроде как переписывание файла настроек возможно, см. основной сайт [assign values to application.properties file Spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51811790/) и связанный вопрос [Write/Update properties file value in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31334977/)

Comment: Переписывание файла настроек не имеет никакого смысла, потому что контекст спринг приложения собирается при запуске и изменение пропертей после этого не будет иметь никакого влияния. Если нужна некая переменная, которая может меняться со временем, то ее стоит хранить или в БД или в енвайронменте и подтягивать оттуда, соответственно @Value не подходит для этих целей.

Comment: @NowhereMan - попробовал. Когда всё лежит отдельными файлами - да, запись работает и при следующем старте подхватится. Но упаковка в jar уже сводит это на нет. Вдобавок - ограничения из моего предыдущего комментария никуда не делись - нужно знать активный профиль, а само значение может быть (например) в env. Может, есть какие-то сценарии, где такая запись будет решать поставленную задачу... но мне такие задачи как-то не фантазируются..

Comment: @AlekseiGaile, спасибо это то что я хотел узнать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ из комментариев:
Переписывание файла настроек не имеет никакого смысла, потому что контекст спринг приложения собирается при запуске и изменение пропертей после этого не будет иметь никакого влияния. Если нужна некая переменная, которая может меняться со временем, то ее стоит хранить или в БД или в енвайронменте и подтягивать оттуда, соответственно @Value не подходит для этих целей. –
@AlekseiGaile